# Symbols on axis tick labels

Tags: matlab, label, matlab-figure

In the code below, I want to change the x-axis so that it shows as 0, a0, 2a0, 3a0... instead of very small numbers. Also, how can I show only the desired ticks, say, 0 and 3a0?

```
a0 = 5.59e-11;
X = linspace(0,5*a0,100);
A = 3;
B = a0/2;
Y = gampdf(X,A,B);
plot(X,Y);
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-axis-parameters.html#f6-29060

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
a0 = 5.59e-11; 
X = linspace(0,5*a0,100);
A = 3;
B = a0/2;
Y = gampdf(X,A,B);
plot(X,Y);

set(gca,'XTick',[0:a0:a0*5])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0','a0','2a0','3a0','4a0','5a0'})
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0','','','3a0','',''})
```